# How to better seal and/or adjust a metal cellar door / bulkhead?

Tags: doors, basement

First of all, I am not exactly sure what the door is called. I have a metal outside door leading to steps into my basement. I have always just called it the basement/cellar door but it seems like other people refer to it as a storm door or bulkhead ? It looks like

[image]
<sup>(via google images).</sup>

Names aside I am looking to put a better seal on the door when it is closed. I can see quite a bit of daylight at the bottom and sides of the folding doors when they are closed. I want to keep the gaps as small as possible to hopefully keep out insects/pests from crawling through. Searching has just lead me to instructions for installing the door which I don't need.

Comment: Yes, that is nearly universally called a "steel bulkhead." While it is a very common method of getting into a cellar, there are others, so "cellar door" is a bit more generic/less specifically identifies the object you are dealing with. Short of replacing it, I don't know that they can be tightened up any - every one I've ever seen has a separate door in the cellar wall to actually keep heat/air inside, as they don't really seal at all well (newer ones _may_ seal better, but I'd check that rather than assume before spending any money on a replacement.)